# Invalid context when snackbar action is used on another page

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a system where the user adds an item to a playlist and a snackbar shows a success message. The snackbar also has an action to open up that playlist with `Navigator.of()`. Since this task opens up a new page to show the playlists, the context used in `Navigator.of()` becomes invalid. I've put the exact error below:

```
FlutterError (Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.)
```

This is my Snackbar:

```dart
SnackBar(
  content: Text("Added to playlist"),
  action: SnackBarAction(
  label: "OPEN",
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
      "/music/albumscreen",
      // Album info (used on the album screen, not relevant for this question)
      arguments: snapshot.data![index]);
    },
  ),
),
```

Is there a way to navigate to a new page when the context is invalid?

Comment: You need to pass the buildContext from the build method to show the shackbar

Comment: @towhid The snackbar is showing fine (using ScaffoldMessenger.Of()), it's just the action that isn't working.

Comment: that means you are using wrong context here `Navigator.of(context)...`

Comment: @towhid It's invalid because the page that makes that snackbar gets immediately popped. I was wondering if I could call Navigator from anywhere, since the snackbar button could theoretically be used anywhere in the app.